# Access parent elements from Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, entity, entity-framework-5

I need to retrieve the value in a hidden field (like Parent Id) in the parent view from a partial view. I searched everywhere but people seem to be doing it the other way around (access partial view elements from parent).

Comment: Is that client side or server side?

Comment: Yeah I'm confused.  He's talking about Partial View but then has it under the JQuery tag... ?

Comment: Ok, maybe I shouldn't have tagged JQuery. I think when a page is rendered in MVC3, so this should be more of a razor question? Much like how we acces @Module.Id, I want to get the parent view elements from within the partial view. This would be ideal: @ParentView.("elementname").Value or something like that if it exists.

Comment: Why don't you just add the property you need to the model used by the partial?

Comment: If i'm adding a new item, it doesn't have any values for any properties. I have a sortorder column which I want calculated in the parent view. the child view needs to store it to add the new item.

Comment: can you show some code how you are including the partial view inside the parent and where/how do you want to get the parents view id?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access Parent Model from partial view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322180/access-parent-model-from-partial-view)